# I don't understand this error: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to run this code from [here](https://abhishekds.com/2016/04/19/retrieve-all-stock-symbols-from-yahoo-finance-using-python/):

```
import re, sys, time, string
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import logging

class FetchAllSybols(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # URL
        # default m (market) - IN, t (type) - S (stock)
        self.sym_start_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/lookup/stocks?t=S&m=IN"
        self.sym_page_url = '&b=0'#page
        self.sym_alphanum_search_url = '&s=a' #search alphabet a
        self.sym_full_url = ''
        self.alphabet_str_to_search = string.ascii_lowercase # full alphabet
        self.sym_info = {}
        self.header = "SymbolId,Full Name, Type, Exchange, URL\n" 

    def set_alphabet_in_url(self, alphabet):
        """ 
        Set the alphabet portion of the url by passing the alphabet.
        :param alphbet (str): can be alphabet.
        """
        self.sym_alphanum_search_url = '&s=' + str(alphabet)

    def set_pagenumber_in_url(self, pageno):
        """ 
        Set the page portion of the url by passing the pageno.
        :param pageno (str): page number.
        """
        self.sym_page_url = '&b=' + str(pageno)


    def gen_next_url(self):
        """ 
        Creates the full url necessary for sym scan by joining the search parameter and page no.
        """
        self.sym_full_url =  self.sym_start_url + self.sym_alphanum_search_url + self.sym_page_url    

    def get_data_from_next_page(self):
        self.gen_next_url()
        print ("Fetching data from URL", self.sym_full_url)
        req = urllib2.Request(self.sym_full_url, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
        html = None
        counter = 0
        while counter < 10:
            try:
                html = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
                logging.error(error.read())
                logging.info("Will try 10 times with 2 seconds sleep")
                time.sleep(2) 
                counter += 1
            else:
                break

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html")
        return soup

    def get_all_valid_symbols(self):
        """ 
        Scan all the symbol for one page. The parsing are split into odd and even rows.
        """
        soup = self.get_data_from_next_page()
        table = soup.find_all("div", class_="yui-content")
        table_rows = table[0].find_all('tr')
        for table_row in table_rows:
            if table_row.find('td'):
                if table_row.contents[2].text != 'NaN':
                    self.sym_info[table_row.contents[0].text]=[table_row.contents[1].text,
                                                               table_row.contents[3].text,
                                                               table_row.contents[4].text,
                                                               table_row.a["href"]]

    def get_total_page_to_scan_for_alphabet(self, alphabet):
        """ 
        Get the total search results based on each search to determine the number of page to scan.
        :param alphabet (int): The total number of page to scan
        """
        self.sym_start_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/lookup/stocks?t=S&m=IN&r="
        self.sym_page_url = '&b=0'#page
        self.sym_alphanum_search_url = '&s='+alphabet

        soup = self.get_data_from_next_page()
        total_search_str = (str(soup.find_all("div", id="pagination")))

        #Get the number of page
        total_search_qty = re.search('of ([1-9]*\,*[0-9]*).*',total_search_str).group(1)
        total_search_qty = int(total_search_qty.replace(',','', total_search_qty.count(',')))
        final_search_page_count = total_search_qty/20 #20 seach per page.

        return final_search_page_count


    def get_total_sym_for_each_search(self, alphabet):
        """ 
        Scan all the page indicate by the search item.
        The first time search or the first page will get the total number of search.
        Dividing it by 20 results per page will give the number of page to search.
        :param alphabet(str)
        """
        # Get the first page info first
        self.set_pagenumber_in_url(0)
        total_page_to_scan =  self.get_total_page_to_scan_for_alphabet(alphabet)
        logging.info('Total number of pages to scan: [%d]'% total_page_to_scan)

        # Scan the rest of the page.
        # may need to get time to rest
        for page_no in range(0,total_page_to_scan+1,1):
            self.set_pagenumber_in_url(page_no*20)
            self.gen_next_url()
            logging.info('Scanning page number: [%d] url: [%s]  ' % (page_no, self.sym_full_url))          
            self.get_all_valid_symbols()

    def serach_for_each_alphabet(self):
        """ 
        Sweep through all the alphabets to get the full list of shares.
        """
        for alphabet in self.alphabet_str_to_search:
            logging.info('Searching for : [%s]' % alphabet)
            self.set_alphabet_in_url(alphabet)
            self.get_total_sym_for_each_search(alphabet)

    def dump_into_file(self):
        '''
        Store all symbols into a csv file.
        '''
        f = open('Symbol_Info.csv', 'w')
        f.write(self.header)

        for key in sorted(self.sym_info):
            values = self.sym_info[key]
            sym = key+','
            for value in values:
                sym += str(value) + ','
            sym += '\n'
            f.write(sym)
        f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = logging.getLogger()
    root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    root.addHandler(ch)

    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler("dump.log")
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    root.addHandler(fileHandler)

    f = FetchAllSybols()
    f.alphanum_str_to_search = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    f.serach_for_each_alphabet()
    f.dump_into_file()
```

I've been getting this error.  I did some googling and still don't have an idea what it means:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xmizer/PycharmProjects/StockProject/venv/hello_world.py", line 157, in <module>
    f.serach_for_each_alphabet()
  File "/Users/xmizer/PycharmProjects/StockProject/venv/hello_world.py", line 122, in serach_for_each_alphabet
    self.get_total_sym_for_each_search(alphabet)
  File "/Users/xmizer/PycharmProjects/StockProject/venv/hello_world.py", line 109, in get_total_sym_for_each_search
    for page_no in range(0,total_page_to_scan+1,1):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  I made the change to this line as you all recommended:
final_search_page_count = total_search_qty // 20

But now, I'm getting this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a script that was written for `Python 2` in `Python 3`. In `Python 2` the division operator yields an integer, in `3` it yields a `float`:

*Python 2*:

```
>>> 20 / 10
2
>>> range(0, 20/10)
[0, 1]
```

While, *Python 3*:

```
>>> 20 / 10
2.0
>>> range(0, 20/10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Either run the script with `Python 2` or change the operator in:

```
final_search_page_count = total_search_qty/20
```

to:

```
final_search_page_count = total_search_qty // 20
```

which yields an `int` as the result.

Comment: Thanks.  That solved that program.

Now when I re-run it, I get this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @TorontoUser in general, trying to run a `Python 2` program in `Python 3` will result in issues all the time. I'd really leave the script as it was originally and run it with `Python 2`.

Answer (score 1):

`final_search_page_count = total_search_qty/20`

I dont know python but the problem seems to be that in the line above should round up to the nearest integer.

This is a smaller case with the same problem:

`range(1, 3.33, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The `range()` function is expecting an integer, while `total_page_to_scan` is a float value. You should find a way to return an int in your `get_total_page_to_scan_for_alphabet()`:

```
def get_total_page_to_scan_for_alphabet(self, alphabet):
    ...
    return int(final_search_page_count)
```

In addition, you did a small typo in `serach_for_each_alphabet()`.

Comment: Thanks.

I think serach_for_each_alphabet() is spelled correctly.  At least, that's how the author spelled it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Jim, you can use the following to ensure an integer result.

```
final_search_page_count = total_search_qty // 20
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
final_search_page_count = int(total_search_qty / 20)
```

This is important because `range()` takes 3 arguments that are all integers (start, finish, increment).